# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jpa

When I upgraded my tomcat from 7 to 8.5 and jdk from 7 to 8, I am getting below errors while starting my tomcat.

Spring version: 4.1.8.RELEASE

I changed below pom entries too, but nothing seems to be working. Please have a look and let me know what I need to do to resolve this issue.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

to

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.47</version>
    </dependency>
```

to

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

The `entityManagerFactory()`

```
 @Bean
 public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.rest.entity" });
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider");
        properties.put("hibernate.current_session_context_class","thread");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "false");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        return properties;
    }
```

Tomcat stdErr.logs

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/rest/configuration/JPAConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1572)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)          at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:960)          at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:749)          at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)          at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:664)         at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:536)            at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:490)          at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1183)          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:992)          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4931)            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5241)            at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)          at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)          at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)            at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:630)         at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1842     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)          at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z          at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:924)         at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:282)        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:359)        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2316)        at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2299)          at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2043)         at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1543)            at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)         at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:279)           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:124)         at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)          at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)           at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)          at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1885)          at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1843)         at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityanagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)           at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)          at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398)           at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)          at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)          at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)         at rg.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1631)         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)        ... 29 more
            Jul 28, 2017 12:18:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
    SEVERE: Servlet [dispatcher] in web application [/TGARest] threw load() exception        java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.isValid(I)Z            at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.DelegatingConnection.isValid(DelegatingConnection.java:924)         at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnection.validate(PoolableConnection.java:282)            at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.validateConnection(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:359)            at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.validateConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2316)            at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2299)          at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:2043)         at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1543)        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcServicesImpl.java:279)           at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:124)         at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)          at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)           at
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AbstractMethodError.html

Comment: Java8 support JDBC 4.1 you are using a non JDBC4.1 driver.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, but I solved it by downloading the updated [JDBC Oracle driver for Java 7 and 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/jdbc-drivers-12c-download-1958347.html).

Comment: Solved it for me as well. Was using jdbc5 (oracle 11, etc..) updated to jdbc7 and worked.